# Add Default Rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert default rows into a result set if the LEFT JOIN is NULL.
For example if Jane has no roles, I want to return some default ones in the results.

A query like this will return the following:

`SELECT * FROM employees  LEFT OUTER JOIN roles ON roles.employee_id = employees.id`

```
Employee ID | Employee Name | Role ID | Role Name
1           | John          | 1       | Admin
1           | John          | 2       | Standard
2           | Jane          | NULL    | NULL
```

I want to return:

```
Employee ID | Employee Name | Role ID | Role Name
1           | John          | 1       | Admin
1           | John          | 2       | Standard
2           | Jane          | NULL    | Admin
2           | Jane          | NULL    | Standard
```

Is there a good way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
SELECT e.*, r.*
FROM employees e
JOIN roles r ON r.employee_id = e.id
UNION ALL
SELECT e.*, NULL, default_name
FROM employees e
JOIN (VALUES ('Admin'), ('Standard')) AS roles(default_name)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM roles r
  WHERE r.employee_id = e.id
)
```

I don't think there's a (good) way around the `UNION` because a `LEFT JOIN` introduces only a single row per unmatched row. You might be able to lift out the join against the `employees` table though:

```
SELECT e.*, r.*
FROM employees e,
LATERAL (
  SELECT r.id, r.name
  FROM roles r
  WHERE r.employee_id = e.id
UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, default_name
  FROM (VALUES ('Admin'), ('Standard')) AS roles(default_name)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM roles r
    WHERE r.employee_id = e.id
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the first query and it doesn't seem to like like this part `JOIN (VALUES ('Admin'), ('Standard')) AS roles(default_name)`

Comment: @Dex Can you provide the table definitions and some example data as sql, so that it could be run in e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14?